# How to do deep pagination for solr result grouping?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I use the result grouping of solr 8 to query some information, but there are some cases where the rows are going to be too big.

There is the recommendation to use the cursorMark for the pagination of results, but it seems that for result grouping the cursorMark is not allowed. How to deal with deep pagination in this case?